# In Datatable excel export, decimal values with % symbol are getting rounded off

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables, decimal, export-to-excel

I am trying to export Datatable to excel sheet. Datatable has a column with decimal values and % symbol. After exporting, the decimal values are getting rounded off. But I need decimal values with % symbol to be present in the excel sheet. Can anyone help me with it. Thanks. fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/xevpdeo1/23/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var xlsBuilder = {
  filename: 'business-group-sharers-',
  sheetName: 'business-group-sharers-',
  exportOptions: {
   columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
  }
}
$('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    $.extend(true, {}, xlsBuilder, {
      extend: 'excel'
    })
  ]
 });
});

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2010/07/14</td>
    <td>99.021%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shad Decker</td>
    <td>Regional Director</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>2008/11/13</td>
    <td>87.96%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
    <td>Singapore</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>2011/06/27</td>
    <td>77.77%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Donna Snider</td>
    <td>Customer Support</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>2011/01/25</td>
    <td>92.07%</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are saved correctly, but the number format is set to **0%** instead of **0.00%**.

Try to set the number format on columns:

```
<td style='mso-number-format:"0.00%"'>99.021%</td>
```